# Extracting single representative sequence plot from seqrep using group in TraMineR

Tags: r, traminer

I am trying to reproduce the plots made by `seqrep` using the `group=` option in `TraMineR` because I want to have an image file with representative sequences for each group to use in a presentation. It seems that I am missing an important part in my syntax as subsetting the sequence object produces very different results from the on-board `group` option in `TraMineR`. As you can see in the pictures below the representative sequences identified by the `seqrep` differ strongly.
Do you know what part is missing or wrong in my syntax?

```
library(TraMineR)
library(WeightedCluster)

data(mvad)
mvad.alphabet <- c("employment", "FE", "HE", "joblessness", "school",
                   "training")
mvad.labels <- c("Employment", "Further Education", "Higher Education",
                 "Joblessness", "School", "Training")
mvad.scodes <- c("EM", "FE", "HE", "JL", "SC", "TR")

## Define sequence objects
mvad.seq <- seqdef(mvad[, 17:86], alphabet = mvad.alphabet, 
                   states = mvad.scodes, labels = mvad.labels, 
                   weights = mvad$weight, xtstep = 6)

## Defining cost matrices for OM - custom and transition based
subm.trate <- seqsubm(mvad.seq, method="TRATE")

## Computing dissimilarity matrices
mvad.ham <- seqdist(mvad.seq, method="HAM", sm=subm.trate)

## Clustering OM dissimilarities
wardCluster <- hclust(as.dist(mvad.ham), method = "ward",
                      members = mvad$weight)
clust4 <- cutree(wardCluster, k = 4)

## Plotting representative sequences
seqrplot(mvad.seq, criterion="dist", group=clust4, dist.matrix=mvad.ham, 
         withlegend=FALSE, border=NA, weighted=TRUE, stats=FALSE)
seqrplot(mvad.seq[clust4==2,], criterion="dist", dist.matrix=mvad.ham, 
         withlegend=FALSE, border=NA, weighted=TRUE, stats=FALSE)
```

**Four groups of representative sequences: see second group**
[image: Four groups of representative sequences]
**Second group of representative sequences**
[image: Second group of representative sequences]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When subsetting the state sequence object, you should subset accordingly the dissimilarity matrix

```
seqrplot(mvad.seq[clust4==2,], criterion="dist", 
         dist.matrix=mvad.ham[clust4==2, clust4==2], 
         withlegend=FALSE, border=NA, weighted=TRUE, stats=FALSE)
```

Falling to do so, `seqrep` would use wrong distances to determine the representative sequences.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! Actually, I had tried this approach before I have asked it here. Then, it did not work but your answer encouraged me to have a second look: At first, it did not work as I had used `seqdist(..., full.matrix=FALSE)` for my original big dataset and I always got an error `incorrect number of dimensions`. I was thinking that this was unimportant therefore I did not include in my example code. I wonder how `seqrplot(..., group=clust4)` gets around this with "half" a distance matrix?

Comment: Somehow, I am not able to get really stable results with my big dataset (dissimilarity matrix ~ 1 GB). In some cases, the plots made by the `group` option or using subsets as in your answer are equal. However, some other plots, especially of large clusters, still differ. Could there be a problem with subsetting large distance matrices?

Comment: This is perhaps a consequence of the random sorting of ties when sorting the sequences according to the chosen criterion (`"dist"` in your case). Try to control by setting a `seed`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I have tried `set.seed()` but it did not solve the difference between the plots. I guess it has something to do with the weights as the differing plots using subsets like `dist.matrix=mvad.ham[clust4==2, clust4==2]` instead of the option `group=` included more sequences and still had lower coverage, though the weighted n is always equal. What really puzzles me: only half of the plots differ and the other half is just fine. It affects the largest groups and some of the smaller groups.